# Why does Dir.glob not work in Rails console/runner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Dir.glob("*.jpg") {|_| puts 'hello'}
```

This works perfectly fine in IRB or a regular Rails script, but fails in Rails Console or a rails runner script. Which is irritating because I really need to use it. Google has no information on this that I can find. What's the deal?

Comment: What do you mean "fails"? Throws an error?

Comment: @Gareth it just doesn't execute at all. Nothing happens. If I run `ruby foo.rb` I see lots of 'hellos'. If I run `rails runner foo.rb` I see nothing at all. Yet if I put 'puts hello' *outside* of the Dir.glob call, that works in both contexts. The same happens in the Rails console -- it just totally ignores Dir.glob calls.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any JPG files in the root level of your app vs where you run `ruby foo.rb`. I don't have any in mine, but if I tweak your code to this:

```
Dir.glob("**/*.jpg") {|_| puts _}
```

I get all of my jpg assets like I'd expect.